# How do I login to Roundcube admin?

Tags: ubuntu, email, ubuntu-16.04, roundcube

I did nothing but more than follow the tutorial here (https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/install-roundcube-webmail-ubuntu-16-04-nginx-mariadb-php7) and I can successfully access to my webmail URL.

However, the issue is that I have no idea what are the admin credentials to login to my Roundcube webmail. It is the first time ever I use Roundcube, after switching from Squirrelmail. I am using a self-managed VPS and I have spent average 3 hours during the setup process.

I have successfully supplied a valid database credentials and 'finished' the installation process by visiting `http://ip/install/`. Why the quotes?  Because I can't login to my Roundcube admin page to administer and add new email addresses.

Therefore, can you please explain to me what I have to do? I have looked around for continuous hours and I don't really know what to do.

PS: In Squirrelmail I used `adduser` and `passwd` commands in Shell to create the admin users, but I'm not sure if it's the same for Roundcube or I am wrong? Will they have full admin access? I am not using shared / hosting. I am using a Virtual Private Server

Comment: Non registered accounts work on cookies. If you're constantly getting logged out, there's something odd going on. However, using answers as a way to reply to things simply dosen't work with the Q&A model Super User uses. We've suggested the best option - registering and requesting association with a proper persistent account. Please don't rely on our good will, and patience in converting posts in the wrong place to comments.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe you can do this kind of account level admin in Roundcube (unless there is a plugin, or its new functionality).  Roundcube will use IMAP to check the password for accounts on the system, so you need to create the IMAP accounts in a way consistent with your mail program.

I note that while it may be possible to have an admin interface that works on some installs, it certainly won't work on all - for example, there is no requirement to have a system account if you are using (for example) Dovecot, and Roundcube could not know how to update the account.

Comment: Correct. My roundcube uses Dovecot as the imap server. Users are created on the system as normal (useradd XXXX).

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I have followed what you have said and I still can't login. Below are the commands I typed in Shell: adduser me # To create a user 'me' passwd me # To assign the password service dovecot restart # To apply changes After, I tried logging in to my webmail using me@domain.tld and the password I assigned to it. That's still not working.

Comment: This sounds to me like a Dovecot issue, and should be a separate question - complete with Dovecot configs.  Before doing this though, can you confirm if this is the same Dovecot install you had for Squirrel mail and if logging in works from Outlook/Evolution/Thunderbird/your favourite IMAP client.

Comment: Replying to @davidgo 1. Please tell me the configs you would like for me to attach.
2. The installation is fresh. I have reinstalled the server before starting to install Roundcube.
3. I do not know how to test logging in with external IMAP clients. I have a iCloud email address, however; please tell me what to do.

Comment: @MrStevenWills Can you please take all the hints we have been giving you and merge your accounts? See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.